# In matplotlib, group bars of plotted data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use my sample data to plot it on a barplot but I would like to group the data which is higher than 10. Here is the code and sample data with the sample graph.

```
g = sns.barplot( x= "X",
                 y= "Y" , 
                 color = '#133155',
                 data = df)
g10.set_ylabel('Y')
g10.set_xlabel('X');
```

data

```
+--------------+-------------+
|X             |            Y|
+--------------+-------------+
|            11|           13|
|            14|            4|
|            17|            1|
|             3|          579|
|             8|           45|
|            24|            1|
|             7|           79|
|            12|            8|
|             6|          120|
|            21|            1|
|            18|            3|
|            20|            2|
|            10|           18|
|             1|         1141|
|            23|            1|
|             5|          202|
|             2|          902|
|            19|            2|
|             9|           39|
+--------------+-------------+
```

Sample Graph

[image]

Comment: Updated with code and sample data

Comment: So, it is rather a seaborn, not a matplotlib question? Is this a pandas dataframe your data are stored in? Please add the tag, if true.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this is to relabel the x values that are greater than 10 into a single group, and then plot using the column with the new value. `df['x_'] = df.x.where(df.x.le(10), 11)` and then plot with `'x_'` instead of `'x'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas-series-clip) your data so that any `X` values above 10 are set to 10 (if that is what you want, if it is 11 then set that instead), then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) `X` and find the `sum` of all the `Y` values.

#### In total

```py
clipped = df.groupby(df["X"].clip(upper=10))["Y"].sum()
sns.barplot(x=clipped.index, y=clipped, color="#133155")
```

will give you
[image]

Comment: Clipped is an alternative function of filter but in my case is half of the solution because the main point is to make a group of the data (with summation) that is higher than 10 and plot it within a bar.

Comment: Can you explain what you want that isn't given by my answer? Clipping is not filtering (note that the 10 bar in the plot above contains everything with `X >= 10`)

Comment: Yes, I checked with my data (due to confidentiality, I shared another sample of data as an example) it looks grouped and correct. Thank you for your answer and comment